# Assigning another variable from a different class in an @IBAction?

Tags: ios, swift, oop

In my GameScene.swift file, I have the following member variable **"chosenBall"** that I want to assign in another file called ChooseBall.swift.

```
class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {
    internal var chosenBall: BallType!
}
```

My ChooseBall.swift file looks like this.

```
class ChooseBall: UIViewController {
    @IBAction func chooseBeachBall(sender: UIButton) {
        chosenBall = BallType.BeachBall
    }
}
```

I am getting a compiler error saying:

```
Use of unresolved identifier 'chosenBall'
```

How can I fix it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't used SpriteKit so I do not know the basics on where and when to instantiate Scenes.

However, the error you are getting is because you have not created an instance of GameScene and made that accessible from your view controller.

A possible solution could be the following code, but again, I'm not sure when or where the scene should be instantiated.

```
class ChooseBall: UIViewController {
    var scene = GameScene()

    @IBAction func chooseBeachBall(sender: UIButton) {
        scene.chosenBall = BallType.BeachBall
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, thanks! This is the right idea, but I realize I need an argument to be passed in GameScene. I'm curious what to pass in this case because in GameViewController.swift, I called it with the following: 

        let skView = view as! SKView
        scene = GameScene(size: skView.bounds.size)

This does not seem to be working in my other file.

Comment: MVC is your guide here.  A game model class would contain choosenBall. Maybe its one ball for all game levels or each level has its own instance of a ball; whatever.  The ChoosenBall UIViewController passes through user choices to the model.  The GameScene class reads  the model's choosenBall and instantiates that in the UI.